# How can I get cells on the right using colspan attribute?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have tried this:

```html
<table class="travaux">
  <tr>
    <th>Nature de l’opération</th>
    <th>Unité</th>
    <th>Quantité</th>
    <th>P.U (dh)</th>
    <th>Coût (dh)</th>
    <th>N.J.T</th>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Coût total     :   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">TVA (20%) :    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">T.T.C            :   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```css
.techniques{
  width: 70%;
}
.techniques,.techniques th, .techniques td{
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.techniques td{
  border-top: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

to get this:
[image: expected]
but I only get it like this:
[image]
please Could anyone tell me how I can get total section on the right instead of left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="border-left: none;border-bottom: none;"></td>
    <td colspan="3">Coût total     :   </td>
</tr>
```

that should do it. You can't just use 3 cols, when you got a 6 col layout

Comment: Thank you it works I should use two colspan of 3, but code's style doesn't remove border at bottom and left! I think I shoud remove them with css?